# Moment.js startOf is returning end of day

Tags: node.js, express, momentjs

I am passing in the following date through query string: 2020-09-23

I am trying to figure out why the below code with the doesn't work comment above it is not working.

```
// If figure here I should only have to convert to a moment once
const momentDate = moment.utc(req.query.dateTime);

// Doesn't work
const startOfDay = momentDate.startOf('day');
const endOfDay = momentDate.endOf('day');
```

**This is what I am getting:**
console.log(startOfDay) = Moment<2020-09-23T23:59:59Z>
console.log(endOfDay) = Moment<2020-09-23T23:59:59Z>

```
// Works (when I directly pass in the query string param)
const startOfDay = moment.utc(req.query.dateTime).startOf('day');
const endOfDay = moment.utc(req.query.dateTime).endOf('day');
```

console.log(startOfDay) = Moment<2020-09-23T00:00:00Z>
console.log(endOfDay) = Moment<2020-09-23T23:59:59Z>

Comment: In your "working" example, you're using `moment` and not `moment.utc` does it still work if you use `moment.utc`?

Comment: @Rastalamm Yes, sorry should have put it there.

Comment: `.startOf` and `.endOf` *mutate* the existing date (see e.g. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/), so I'd expect different behaviour depending on whether you have one or two moment objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are doing on the same object `momentDate`, so same reference, so the safer way is to work on the copy of that object by cloning that `momentDate` with `clone()` method

```
const momentDate = moment.utc(new Date())

const startOfDay = momentDate.clone().startOf("day")
const endOfDay = momentDate.clone().endOf("day")

console.log(startOfDay)
console.log(endOfDay)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a timezone problem, try this approach.

```
let myDate = new Date();

const timezoneOffset = moment(myDate).utcOffset();

moment(myDate).utc().add(timezoneOffset, 'minutes').startOf('day').format();
moment(myDate).utc().add(timezoneOffset, 'minutes').endOf('day').format();
```

Comment: this is the exact solution I was looking for. thanks and upvoted